# Kafka Listener Concurreny - How to handle Stop/Idle events fired from 6 threads

Tags: spring-kafka

I have 2 Kafka Listeners Daily/Weekly. Daily has autoStartup = true and 
Weekly has autoStartup = false. I have an endpoint to stop Daily that is running and start Weekly. Once the Weekly finished consuming messages, I wait for idle event ( set to 1 minute ) to trigger, where I stop Weekly. Now I'm listenting to STOP event on Weekly where I start Daily. The problem now is I have concurrency set to 6. so I'm getting 6 Idle events and 6 Stop events. I have handled like below. I would like to know if this is a good practice or is there anything better?

I gather all the Daily stop events in a ConcurrentHashMap. Once it reaches the concurreny count, that mean all 6 daily listener threads are stopped and can start the Weekly Listener.

```
private void processDailyStopEvent(ConsumerStoppedEvent event)
    {
        LOGGER.info("Processing DAILY Stop events");
        KafkaMessageListenerContainer source = (KafkaMessageListenerContainer) event.getSource();
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer container = (ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer) event.getContainer(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.class);

        eventMap.get(“dailyStop”).add(source.getListenerId());
        LOGGER.info("Added ListenerId {} to Map<dailyStop>", source.getListenerId());

        if (eventMap.get(“dailyStop”).size() == container.getConcurrency()) {
            LOGGER.info("All DAILY Stop events are captured. Clearing the Map<dailyStop>");
            eventMap.get(“dailyStop”).clear();

            LOGGER.info("Starting WEEKLY Consumer now.");
            kafkaService.startWeeklyConsumer();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a reasonable approach.

Alternatively, you can just wait for the concurrent container's stop event (where the source is equal to the container) - it is published after all the child containers are stopped.

Comment: Thanks Gary Russell. I'll implement the approach you have suggested.

Comment: However, the concurrent container doesn't emit idle events; you will still need to wait for the 6 events from discrete containers to ensure the whole container is idle. Each child may publish multiple idle events before they are all idle; depending on your record distribution and processing time.

Comment: I got it! I'll implement this approach only for stop events! Thank you Gary Russell!

Comment: I have one more question on how to pass a variable in @EventListener. I asked this question in a separate thread.  How to use a SPEL here for 'qux-'.                                           
 ```@EventListener(condition = "event.listenerId.startsWith('qux-')")
    public void eventHandler(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
        ...
    }```

Comment: You don't have to comment here about other questions; I get notifications for new questions for the tags that I monitor.

Comment: I did not receive any Concurrent container's stop event. I just got 6 Child Container's stop event only. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry; I didn't notice which event you are listening for; you need to listen for `ContainerStoppedEvent`s instead.

Comment: Thanks Gary Russell! I'll listen to ContainerStoppedEvent and Update this thread with the result.

Comment: I changed my code to listen to ContainerStoppedEvent and wait for the last event where source is equal to ConcurrentContainer and then start the other container. Everything is working perfectly. Thanks @Gary Russell!

Comment: `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer container = event.getContainer(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.class);

        if (container.equals(event.getSource())) {
            log.info("Parent Consumer Stop event received.");
        }`