# process kafka topic one after another

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am new to kafka.

In our project, there is a source system which is going to post different types of json messages(type1, type2) in different topics. we have spring micro services with kafka listeners listening to those topics. we have to convert source message to different json format and send it to another REST API but there is concern here that we have to process ALL the type1 messages first before sending the typ2 messages. incase if we send type2 earlier than the type1, we will get errors from the REST API as it can not process type2 without having type1.

we have a parameter in each messages which tells us whether the messages is type1 or type2

we thought of doing it using these approaches. i am still reading about spring kafka and do not even know these are possible so please forgive if something is stupid or not possible.

1. read all the messages and process type1 first before processing type2(keep the message in kafka topic itself). is this possible ? it is like if message is type2, do not do anything now.
2. read each message and process only type1 and if it is type2, keep it in db to process it later after completing all type 1 messages. To do this, i need to know whether all type1 message is processed. how do i check this ?
3. Thought of asking source team to process type1 messages in particular topic and type 2 messages in another topic.In spring side, one listner to read type1 topics and another one for type2 topics. Pause the type2 listerner by default. process type1 topics first and if it is done, resume the type2 listener.

or if you can help me in better approach, i will be greatful.

Please help me and let me know if you need any additional details.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, and most efficient, method is to use 2 different topics/listeners, and control the lifecycle of the listener containers (e.g. using idle container events to know when all the type1s have been processed).

See [this question for an example of that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61243095/kafka-listener-concurreny-how-to-handle-stop-idle-events-fired-from-6-threads/61252002#61252002) and [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#events).

1 will work too; simply rewind (seek) the partitions to the initial position and re-process from the same place. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#seek).

Comment: HI Gary, we have done the 2 topics/listernes approach POC and it works fine in local. Thanks for your valuable input. just have one more question, our microservices are deployed in openshift. i am sure that idle event will have no problem in running in one pod.  will it work in multi-pod openshift environment too ? or do i need to do anything extra ?

Comment: If you mean that you have multiple instances of the same service; the partitions will be distributed across those instances; there is no built-in way to prevent instance 1 from starting to process type2s before instance2 has processed all of it's type1s.

Comment: Hi Gary, We have 2 consumers. 1 consumer's autostartup is set to false and another consumer has idle event configured for 1 mins. After 1 min of idle event of consumer 1, we start the consumer 2 to consume those messages. once consumer 2 consumed all the messages, we want to make the consumer 2's auto startup false again(we get messages only next day so if auto-startup true, it starts consuming immediately) and the  stop the idle time event triggering which is happening every 1 min due to no messages in the topic(idle time event needs to be triggered only once for the day).

Comment: As I said, you should enable idle events on the second listener and stop it when it goes idle; then schedule a start of listener2. Autostartup only takes effect when the application is started. Once it is started you have to use stop() and start().

Comment: We implemented the way we said above(2 or 1 topic, multi-partition, multi consumer) and we see issues in some instance where type 2 messages goes before type1. In that scenario, we get error messages from rest API so post the type 2 error-ed out message to error topic. we want to process the error topics messages once the above topic(s) empties all message in all of their partition. how do we do it?. NOTE:We thought of doing 1 topic, 1 partition & 1 instance(POD) with multi threading while posting messages to rest API but it takes lot of time and CPU usages will be more for 1 POD.